# Extract depthmap in Blender using python api

Tags: python, graphics, rendering, blender

I want to obtain a depthmap of a scene using Blender python API. I already have a script that can render a RGB image from a specific view, but it is unclear how to do it for depth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mark as solved if the answer works...

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the *Z* output of the *Render Layers* in the *Node Editor* to a *Viewer*. Then you can render it from python, and access the pixels of the viewer with:

```
pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
```

See this answer for more informations: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27359/13212